# OpenCV cvShowImage function error (in ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-14.04

I use the `cvShowImage` function to show a Image CvMat. But the result is incorrect. The CvMat is 120 * 160 while the result is 120 * 364 (height * width)pixels. The code:

```
void SHOW_IMAGE(const CvMat *pmat, const char str[], int wait)
{
    cout << "channels:" << CV_MAT_CN(pmat->type) << "\n";
    CvMat *mat = cvCloneMat(pmat);
    assert(mat);
    //show it
    cvNamedWindow(str, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //0 1
    cvShowImage(str, mat);
    cvWaitKey(wait); 
    //clear
    cvReleaseMat(&mat);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine.. tested on winxp, visual studio 2010, opencv 2.4.8. Gui Qt 4.8.6.

Comment: Thank you. But The code is not fine on the ubuntu 14.04. I test the cvShowImage function with the CvMat(120 * 380) and the result is correct. I find that the width of image is limited(at least 364). I don't confirm this conclusion.